# Docker no ejecuta mi contenedor

Tags: python, django, docker

estoy generando un contenedor para mi aplicación con el siguiente **dockerfile**

```
FROM django

ADD ./cryptoassistant /cryptoassistant

WORKDIR /cryptoassistant

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/cryptoassistant/manage.py"]

RUN ["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"]

RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]

CMD [ "python", "./manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Cuando construyo el contenedor y lo ejecuto muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se queda aquí, sin hacer nada más, el servidor no parece arrancado porque no puedo acceder al mismo.

Estoy utilizando windows.

¿Alguien sabe por qué no ejecuta el comando?

Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ésta](https://github.com/brunocascio/docker-espanol) página que explican un poco en español acerca de docker

Comment: ¿Por qué, notas que he hecho algo mal? he ejecutado otros dockers y no he tenido problema nunca.

Comment: No, yo lo veo bien, de hecho, por eso no pongo una respuesta, pero quizás incluso ya con tu experiencia y ese articulo puedas debugear mejor que sucede y llegar a la solución. Yo diría que quizás hay un error del lado de django al iniciar, puede ser porque no se instaló un paquete o no se conecta a la base de datos. Pero debes buscar el archivo con el log adecuado

Comment: Eso intento, ver si hay algún log con las salidas de los comandos en docker, pero no lo veo

Comment: Intenta correrlo como _daemon_ pasandole la opción `-d` y luego revisa si el proceso está corriendo con `docker ps -a`

Comment: El proceso se queda corriendo, porque aunque utilice **CTRL + C ** tengo luego que hacer un stop

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82028/discussion-between-german-alzate-and-xboss).

Comment: Por si alguien lo necesita y mientras se encuentra una solución a esta pregunta, he encontrado una opción de generarme un contenedor de otra forma, para ello creo un contenedor vacío y agrego mi proyecto, lo configuro y creo una imagen, que después subo a docker.io y puedo ejecutarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La imagen de django en [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/django/) está *deprecated* en favor de la imagen estandar de python, y no se actualiza desde el 31 de Diciembre de 2016. Es posible que la versión de tu proyecto no sea compatible con la versión desplegada en este container. En la página de dockerhub viene también un ejemplo de como podría hacerse un dockerfile para un proyecto de django que use python 3.4 y postgresql:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Se puede partir de este ejemplo y adaptar la versión de python a usar y las dependencias de base de datos que sean necesarias.